# REG : Custom Dropdown box identification [CAPYBARA]

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, cucumber, capybara

Looking at selecting a value from the dropdown ( custom ) not regular dropdown , It has a lot of dropdown values

I am able to select the first value with the code

find('.selected', :text=>arg1,exact: false).click

But unable to select the remaining values as the Text has a lot of padding spaces! How to tackle this situation

Comment: An example (eg a prototype and/or html) of the dropdown would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the drop-down looks like, but one thing you might do is collect all the options:

```
dropdown = session.find(:css, '#ElementId')                   #customize as needed
options  = dropdown.all(:css, "option").collect {|o| o.text}
```

Then use the index to select from the drop-down:

```
session.select options[3], from: 'ElementId'
```